# Kafka configuration for Spring Integration on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I have a working prototype Spring Boot application which listens on a Kafka queue. Apart from the configuration in `application.yml`, all that is required is a `MessageListener` implementation annotated with `@KafkaListener`.

Am now introducing Spring Integration, and to do so have configured these beans:

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String>
adapter(KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
    KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter =
            new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(container);
    kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(receiver());
    return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
}

@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container() throws Exception {
    ContainerProperties properties = new ContainerProperties(this.topic);
    // set more properties
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory(), properties);
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = ...; // set proerties
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}
```

The application is not starting, and is throwing this error:

```
Parameter 1 of method kafkaListenerContainerFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'kafkaConsumerFactory' in 'KafkaAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'consumerFactory'


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory' in your configuration.
```

This is even though I have defined a `ConsumerFactory` bean.

Running in debug mode, it is apparent that Boot is loading a `KafkaListenerEndpointContainer` bean to listen on the broker:

```
[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Discovered coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483999 rack: null) for group my_group.
```

Then:

```
  KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration#kafkaListenerContainerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: kafkaListenerContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration#kafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.EnableKafkaConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerAnnotationProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaProducerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaProducerListener matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.support.ProducerListener; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration#kafkaTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

I think what is happening is that the Spring Boot\Kafa auto configuration is clashing with the Spring Integration\Kafka setup. What is the correct way to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either use Boot's Consumer factory...

```
@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
    ...
}
```

Or disable kafka auto configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
```